# Get list of users' mailbox folders size larger than a specific amount

Tags: office365, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

In out Office 365 environment I'm trying to get a list of users that have folders in their mailbox with a size larger than 5GB. So far I was able to run this command to get the list of folders and their size:

`Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity Sean | Select-Object name, @{name=”Folder Size (GB)”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.FolderSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/GMB),1)}}`

But the value is not an integer and I can't sort by folder size.

I also tried this script:

````
$i = 0 
$SizeOfFolder = 'Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity Sean | Select-Object @{name=”Folder Size (GB)”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.FolderSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),1)}}'
Foreach($Mbx in $SizeOfFolder)
{
$Converted = [int]($Mbx -replace '\D')
if ($Converted -ge 5)
{
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity Sean | Select-Object name, @{name=”Folder Size (GB)”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.FolderSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),1)}}
}
$i++
}```

And looks like it converted it to integer but did not return any value.
````